# How to generalize a resource function to be used in all controllers for different models?

Tags: php, laravel, api

## **In laravel API Resources:**

I need a dynamic way to generalize a code for all resources to be used in all controllers instead of using resources in all methods for each controller .. for more clarification, I have a trait that includes generalized functions which return  json responses with data and status code, lets take a "sample function" suppose it is  **showAll(Collection $collection)** which is used for returning a collection of data of the specified model for example it is used for returning all users data .. 
**so I need to build a function that call what ever resource of the specified model, knowing that I have many models...**

> a) trait that include showAll method:

```php
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

trait ApiResponser
{
    private function successResponse($data, $code) {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200) {

        $collection = $this->resourceData($collection);

        $collection = $this->filterData($collection);
        $collection = $this->sortData($collection);
        $collection = $this->paginate($collection);
        $collection = $this->cacheResponse($collection);
        return $this->successResponse([$collection, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }

    protected function resourceData(Collection $collection) {
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

> b) usercontroller as a sample

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        // Here the showAll(Collection $collection) is used
        return $this->showAll($users);
    }

}
```

> c) UserResource:

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'identity' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'isVerified' => $this->verified,
            'isAdmin' => $this->admin,
            'createDate' => $this->created_at,
            'updateDate' => $this->updated_at,
            'deleteDate' => $this->deleted_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

**generalize: means used everywhere without code redundancy**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution.. by adding the following method

```
    protected function resourceData($collection) {
        $collection = get_class($collection[0]);

        $resource = 'App\Http\Resources\\' . str_replace('App\\', '', $collection) . 
        'Resource';

        return $resource;
     }
```

1. The `$collection[0]` in the first line of this method will get the
   model you are currently using.
2. `get_class` will get the model name **ex:** **App\User**
3. `'App\Http\Resources\\' . str_replace('App\\', '', $collection)`:
   This will get the path of the resource by adding `'App\Http\Resources\'` before the 
   model
4. `str_replace('App\\', '', $collection)`: will remove `App\ path` from the collection 
   name so `App\User` should be `User`
5. then `'Resource'` would be concatenated with the previous results and the whole 
   string should be like that: `App\Http\Resources\UserResource`
6. So at the end you should return the whole string `App\Http\Resources\UserResource` 
   ,finally you should call the `resourceData()` in 
   the `showAll()` method:

> ```
> protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200) {
>     $collection = $this->resourceData($collection);
>     $collection = $this->filterData($collection);
>     $collection = $this->sortData($collection);
>     $collection = $this->paginate($collection);
>
>     //Calling resourceData() method
>     $resource = $this->resourceData($collection);
>
>     $collection = $this->cacheResponse($collection);
>
>
>     return $this->successResponse([$resource::collection($collection), 'code' => $code], $code);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What about providers, you may load data there and make that data reachable at places where user data can be reachable ?

[laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already made a similar thing like what you said.. my problem is how to get the resource of a specified model.. if you know fractal transformer there was a property called transformer that is used with the models which enables us to get the transformer of whatever the instance of model ... this is my problem ,so I need a similar way to get the resource of model